# Does removing the anchor tags on a Vue.js page for a SP 2013 site make the URLs unclickable?

Tags: anchor-tags

My question involves a SharePoint 2013 site that has some Vue.js component pages and one of the pages displays some text links (i.e. anchor tags .

The question I have is: how do I disable the links on that component page to where the links are no longer clickable, but instead, I can use the "copy to clipboard and paste" method to access the URL.

For example:
payload.body += '

<a href="' + SPCI.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Pages/' + process.env.VUE_APP_PAGE + '#/tr....etc.

I've tried the following:
a) removing the anchor tags (a href=) portion and just leaving the double-quotes, and then delete  the closing anchor tag.
b) remove the 'a' and leave the 'href' while deleting the closing  tag.
** The result for both was that the full URL was being displayed and was still clickable.

Any suggestions/instructions would be greatly appreciated since I'm not a vue.js person and don't know much about something like this and I've researched on Google for a long while and found no one with this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function on the onClick of the link:

```
function onLinkClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback...that helped get me to where I was hoping for...appreciate the help!

Comment: Please vote for the answer